# Compile in a single log all .log that shows Error message

Tags: shell-script, cron, vim

I have many generated logs in /var/opt/log_loc1,/var/opt/log_loc2, /var/opt/log_loc3 from different cron jobs. Instead of looking in each log, is there a way to schedule a cron job that populates the new logfile with all logs that have Error message in them?

Basically I want to populate with all log names and the error in it a new logfile with "all_logs_%Y_%m_%d" as a name. Each day, I will have a new 
all_logs_%Y_%m_%d

Example:
Here's a list of my logfiles in /var/opt/log_loc1

1. InsertSales_2019_08_19.log
2. PurgeHistory_2019_08_19.log
3. Import11_2019_08_19.log
4. ImportSales_2019_08_19.log
5. Import22_2019_08_20.log
6. Import33_2019_08_20.log
7. InsertSales_2019_08_20.log
8. PurgeHistory_2019_08_20.log
9. Import11_2019_08_20.log
10. ImportSales_2019_08_20.log
11. Import22_2019_08_21.log
12. Import33_2019_08_21.log
13. InsertSales_2019_08_21.log
14. PurgeHistory_2019_08_21.log

*Apologies if my question is incomplete

Comment: Since you have a `vim` tag, are you asking for `vim $(grep -l Error /var/opt/log*)` to start vim with a list of files that include the word `Error`?

Comment: Do you want to combine all log *lines* which are somehow marked as errors? In chronological order? Without reprocessing any lines you have already processed (crucial if you have a *lot* of logs)? Please also provide a couple example files with some data and what you expect the result to look like. Because unless you just want a naive `grep Error /var/opt/log* > errors` this is not a trivial task.

Comment: @icarus sorry I am actually a DBA. I usually use vi command in linux.

Comment: @l0b0 i've edited my entry. let me know if that's enough

Comment: OK, you have shown us some typical input filenames. What is a typical output filename that you want and *more* *importantly* what goes into this new file? All the lines containing `Error` from the current logs? Have you considered moving the logs so that instead of /var/opt/log_loc1/InsertSales_2019_08_21.log you have /var/opt/log_loc1/2019/08/21/InsertSales.log which will reduce the number of files in any given directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about `find`?, the easiest way I can think is using it, maybe it's a little rough but it must do the job

`find /var/opt/ -type f -name "*.log" -exec grep -iH 'err\|warn\|fail\|whatever' {} >> total.log \;`

It's not clear for me if you just want to filter all log files (from all the days) or just from today, if you need to filter with date you can use `-mtime` option from `find` or just make a "trick" with `-name` option to only filter, for example, logs from yesterday

`` find /var/opt/ -type f -name "*_`date --date yesterday '+%Y_%m_%d'`.log" -exec grep -iH 'err\|warn\|fail\|whatever' {} >> total.log \; ``

Not sure if this can help you... Other thing that is not clear is, what kind of syntax the logs files have? Coz `find` don't find in alphabetical or numerical order, so you will get a chaotic file. Usually (and must be a dogma), logs start with %Y%m%d_%H:%M or something like that, if that's the case you can `sort` the output of `find` in a way like

`find /var/opt/ -type f -name "*.log" -exec grep -iH 'err\|warn\|fail\|whatever' {} \; sort -no total.log`

I tried this un my `/var/log` and looks like it do the job, but as I said, it's a rough way.

Hope this can help you.

You have more info about the options I used with `find`, `sort` and `grep` in the `man` pages.